# Visual Studio Code React not showing error even after adding jsconfig

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

So I am building a REACT JS project, and after a while I noticed that it doesn't underline undefined functions nor wrong imports, for example if I does that:

```
import React, { useState } from 'reactaeasdfas';
```

it wont say that `reactaeasdfas` is undefined.

After a bit of searching I found that people say that `jsconfig.json` should be initialized.

I found a basic one on the internet:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

This code above does solve the problem that if I call an undefined function, it will underline it in red, but it still doesn't work if I include undefined import.

**Note:** I installed react project via [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Comment: Try to install a plugin like `ESLint` after CRA, you can customize the settings later

Comment: @kekai is there a way to fix that problem without external packages? I mean, in other react projects that I have ( for example cloned from other repositories ) it works just fine without that plugin `ESLint`

Comment: i have installed but after that wrong or missing variable error does not show while typing the code.

Answer (score 10):

Install the ESLint extension for Visual Studio Code - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

More details:

A standard create-react-app package is already using ESLint, so you shouldn't need to make any changes to the app. However, your editor needs to be set up to work with ESLint. For VS Code this is done by installing an extension/plugin. The CRA documentation has more information about setting up editors - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/